# Integers whose digital sum divides the following integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

As is well known, a Niven (or Harshad) number is one which is divisible by its digital sum. Say a number is a pseudo-Niven number if its digital sum divides the number that comes next, such as 31, whose digital sum (4), divides 32.

1. Which are more numerous, Niven or pseudo-Niven numbers?
2. No three consecutive numbers can be pseudo-Niven (unlike Niven, of which one can find up to 20 consecutive numbers all which are Niven). Can gaps between consecutive pseudo-Niven numbers be arbitrarily large?
3. Are infinitely many numbers that are both Niven and pseudo-Niven?

Comment: Experimental testing seems to find Niven numbers to be around $4$ times as numerous as Pseudo-Niven numbers. For example, there are $806087$ Niven numbers and $221916$ pseudo-niven numbers less than $10^7$.

Comment: $10^n+2$ is always Niven numbers while $10^n+1$ is always pseudo-Niven numbers. So there are infinitely many numbers Niven and pseudo-Niven numbers.

Comment: For some more experimental results, there are $61574500$ niven numbers and $17045190$ pseudo-niven numbers below $10^9$. The ratio is actually closer to  $3.6$ than $4$.

Comment: @Asher2211 102 is not a pseudo-Niven, its digital sum (3) does not divide 103.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos $10^n+1$ is  pseudo-Niven numbers while $10^n+2$  is  Niven numbers.